# Trying to use sum value django

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, orm, django-queryset

How can I use the result of this sum in a queryset?

```
query = some_model.objects.aggregate(Sum('some_field'))
```

I already tried this

```
regPeso = test_model.objects.create(test_field_id =1,total_field = query)
```

I got this error

```
Field 'total_field' expected a number but got "{'some_field__sum': x}"
```

What can i do to solve this error?, Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtain the value from the dictionary for a given key by *subscripting*, so:

```
regPeso = test_model.objects.create(
    test_field_id=1,
    total_field=query['some_field__sum']
)
```